# Actualizar una lista por su index

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando con Windows Forms tengo un objeto DataGridView el cual lo pueblo con una lista.
Lo que necesito es que cuando seleccione un elemento de la grilla tomar el index y con ese index hacer la búsqueda en la lista para actualizar una propiedad que tiene.

```
private void dText_keyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = ((DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl) (sender)).EditingControlRowIndex;
        _rowIndex = rowIndex;
        if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            var frm = CompositionRoot.Resolve<FrmCantidad>();
            _hub.Subscribe<SelectedCantidad>(OnCantidadSelected);
            frm.ShowDialog();
            _hub.ClearSubscriptions();
        }
    }

    private void OnCantidadSelected(SelectedCantidad obj)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Valor))
        {
            var list = _saVenta.MostrarVentas().ToList();
            if (list)
            {

            }
                .
        }
    }
```

El DGV lo cargo asignando su propiedad DataSource a la lista.

Comment: ¿A cuál control le pertenece este evento `dText_keyDown`?. Mire esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3578198/4092887).

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave le pertenece al DataGridView